# Debugging git packages given in requirement.txt file for application hosted on Cloud Foundry

Tags: django, cloud-foundry

I am hosting a Django application on Cloud Foundry. In *requirement.txt* file, I am adding my git code (as a package). I have written some print statements to debug my package. Where will I see those print statements.

Or

#### How Can I debug a git package I am adding in requirement.txt file.

I need to check where my code is failing.

I wanted to use a git package in my application. I added it in requirement.txt file and hosted my application on Cloud Foundry. But that package is failing somewhere. So, I wanted to debug where it is failing. I downloaded the package and added print statements in the package code. How can I see those print statements. Or what is the way I can debug, where that package is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see the print statements in my `cf logs app --recent`.

Comment: Anything your application writes during staging, like when running `pip install`, or writes while it's running to STDOUT or STDERR will show up in `cf logs`. This is the preferred option for apps running on CF. If you write directly to a file, that output will not show up in `cf logs`.